# How to batch rename excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a formula that I can use to batch rename all the sheets inside the same excel workbook? Is there a way to create a loop among them? For example, I have a list of 5 fixed sheet names to go with sheet 1-5, then sheet 6-10, sheet 11-15, etc.

Have tried

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.Name = Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

but it does not get me what I want.

Comment: Where is the code, and where is the list located? I mean, In which workbook? In which worksheet and range is the list located? When is this supposed to happen? An idea could be that the code is written in a standard module and is executed by pressing a button. Please do clarify. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66519220/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean with "5 fixed sheet names"? Every sheet name needs to be unique. Do you want to append a suffix/prefix to them?